# Submitting form using mechanize in python

Tags: python, forms, submit, mechanize, submission

I am trying to submit a form to http://apps.fas.usda.gov/esrquery/esrq.aspx in python, using the following code:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mechanize
import datetime 

today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%m/%d/%Y")

url = 'http://apps.fas.usda.gov/esrquery/esrq.aspx'
html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
viewstate = soup.find('input', {'id' : '__VIEWSTATE'})['value']
eventval = soup.find('input', {'id' : '__EVENTVALIDATION'})['value']

br = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory()) 
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
br.open(url)

# fill form

br.select_form("aspnetForm") 
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
br.form['__EVENTTARGET'] = ''
br.form['__EVENTARGUMENT'] = ''
br.form['__LASTFOCUS'] = ''
br.form['__VIEWSTATE'] = viewstate
br.form['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = '41AA5B91'
br.form['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = eventval
br.form['ctl00$MainContent$lbCommodity'] = ['401']
br.form['ctl00$MainContent$lbCountry'] = ['0:0']
br.form['ctl00$MainContent$ddlReportFormat'] = ['10']
br.find_control('ctl00$MainContent$cbxSumGrand').items[0].selected = True
br.find_control('ctl00$MainContent$cbxSumKnown').items[0].selected = False
br.form['ctl00$MainContent$rblOutputType'] = ['2']
br.form['ctl00$MainContent$tbStartDate'] = '01/01/1999'
br.form['ctl00$MainContent$ibtnStart'] = ''
br.form['ctl00$MainContent$tbEndDate'] = today
br.form['ctl00$MainContent$ibtnEnd'] = ''
br.form['ctl00$MainContent$rblColumnSelection'] = ['regular']   

response = br.submit()
```

The response I am getting is essentially just the html code of the site with the form filled out as expected. However, I was expecting an excel file (as I have selected OutputType value of 2)

I think I am missing something on the submission front. Could somebody shed some light on what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but there's more you need to do after submitting.  In this case, just add:

```
doc = response.read()
ofile = '<your path>'
with open(ofile, 'w') as f:
    f.write(doc)
```

I couldn't actually test this on your website at the moment, so I'm just assuming all your settings before this are correct.  I only have Python 3 at work, and mechanize only works on 2.x.  Regardless, this is generally the way you want to retrieve this sort of output.

Comment: When I do this the response is writing the html (with form filled out correctly) to a .xls file (as per my path). There still appears to be something wrong with the submit. What I have noticed is the output has the calendar image for the date input open. Could this be causing the problem? There are the controls 'ctl00$MainContent$ibtnStart' and 'ctl00$MainContent$ibtnEnd' which i have left with blank inputs. Could that potentially be causing the problem?

Comment: Are you able to add any more assistance at all Jeff?

Comment: It looks like the problem is with submit, but I'm not sure why.  For example, after you select the form if you do `for cont in br.controls: print cont.name` you'll see the name of the submit control in there, but if you try to pass `name=...` into submit, it says it doesn't see it.  Also, the output it writes to file is the main page, not the search results, and it doesn't change no matter what you set or don't set on the controls.  Even if you just submit and then try to read the response, you'll see it's on the start page still.  Might need to make this a different question.